# Cefsharp force open certificate selection window

Tags: cefsharp

In Cefsharp, is it possible to force open the certificate selection window after it's been selected before?

I have a small windows forms application written that uses cefsharp to browse a website. The first time the website is accessed, it opens a window asking the user to select a certificate. In the second time, the website uses the previous selected certificate and the window does not show up.

I've trying to find some workarounds for this and the only one I have found is that I can kill the cefsharp browser process, but unfornately this is not an option, so I am looking for a workaround to force open the certificate selection window.

Comment: https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewforum.php?f=6 is a better place to ask this sort of question. CefSharp is just one of many chromium embedded framework(CEF) wrappers. I don't believe CEF supports this directly. You could create a new ChromiumWebBrowser instance with a different RequestContext and you should get prompted for the certificate selection. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#request-context-browser-isolation I'd suggest asking on ceforum (post a link back here for reference)

Comment: Was it a certificate error? In that case there is http://cefsharp.github.io/api/81.3.x/html/M_CefSharp_IRequestContext_ClearCertificateExceptions.htm it might be worth trying anyway if you are using select certificate. http://cefsharp.github.io/api/81.3.x/html/M_CefSharp_Cef_GetGlobalRequestContext.htm